# Setting width to iframe based on browser using jquery not worked in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following code for setting height and width to a div and iframe based on browser window height and width

```
    var newheight = $(document).height();
    var newH = parseInt(newheight) - 170;
    var newHI = parseInt(newheight) - 215;
    var width = $(document).width();
    var newwidth = $('#LeftPane').width();
    var newW = parseInt(width) - (parseInt(newwidth) + 50);
    $('#LeftPane').height(newH);
    $("#ifrforms").height(newHI);
    $("#ifrforms").width(newW);
```

But this code is not working in IE?
It troubles me... if any body knows the solution please help me...

Comment: Any errors? Give us a jsfiddle?

Comment: What happens in IE? Do you see any height/width getting applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var newheight = $(document.body).height();
    var newH = parseInt(newheight) - 170;
    var newHI = parseInt(newheight) - 215;
    var width = $(document.body).width();
    var newwidth = $('#LeftPane').height(newH).width();
    var newW = parseInt(width) - (parseInt(newwidth) + 50);
    $("#ifrforms").height(newHI).width(newW);
```